# System call error while calling a function

Tags: tcl

I am calling a function as below:

```
write_phy 1 0 0x100
```

While the function write_phy is:

```
proc write_phy {phy register value} {
  if { [regexp {^0} $value] } {
        scan $value "%o" value
     }

  if {$::DEBUG} {
       puts [format "Write PHY %s register %s = 0x%0.8X" $phy $register $value]
    }
 # exec ./write_phy.pl $phy $register $value
}

after 1;
```

While executing the function I am getting a system call error though the print statement works properly:

```
Write PHY 1 register 0 = 0x00000000

Disallowed system call: SYS__newselect
```

Other functions in the code are working good.

Please help.

Comment: I didn't find any relation of the code you have given with the error message in terms of `tcl`.  Is the commented perl code being triggered? What it does?

Comment: It executes a perl script but its commented anyways

Comment: Hi Dinesh, I have edited the code: there is "after 1;" at the bottom..which might be causing the problem

Answer (score 0):

If I let the code run on Tcl 8.6 (Raspbian), it tells me that it expected an integer but got "256". What Version of Tcl and what OS are you using? Are you running a Batteries-included Tcl (like Etcl) or some other distro?

P.S. The "after 1" in the global context just pauses one millisecond when loading the script into the interpreter. It has nothing to do with the error itself. I think you can remove it.

Comment: I think the problem is arising because I am compiling the code in codepad.org

Comment: Ah, that would explain it. The `after` command does a `select()` call in its internals (in various ways) but there's no real reason to try the code on codepad in the first place, as that won't have the hardware you're trying to talk to in the first place…